# no such column in table SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

helo i have created a table named produittable, i need to save some data from editText
and after search it in a list, but the logCat says that no column named description_produit
and for me it's there can you please suggest me where am I wrong and how to fix it.

The is my logCat ....

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table produittable has no column named quantite_stock (code 1): , while compiling: insert into produittable(nom_produit,quantite_stock,prix_vente,description_produit) values('nokia','15','90','where plz')
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.tabet.salah_projet.ProduitActivity.insert(ProduitActivity.java:165)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.tabet.salah_projet.ProduitActivity$3.onClick(ProduitActivity.java:56)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-15 11:34:08.902: E/AndroidRuntime(1003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and Database code..

```
public class ProduitActivity extends Activity{
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.produits);
        createDB();
        TextView listeprod =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.link_to_liste);
        listeprod.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChecklisteProduit.class);
                startActivity(i); 
            } 
            });


        Button btnAller=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAller );
        btnAller.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Stock.class);
            startActivity(i); 
        } 
        });
      //do insert
        Button btnAjout=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAjout );
        btnAjout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        insert();
        } 
        });
        Button btnClear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear );
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        clear();
        }
        }); 
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    CreateMenu(menu);
    return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
    return MenuChoice(item);
    }

    private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
    {
    MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Insert");
    {
    mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut('i');
    mnu1.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add);
    }
    MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, "Search");
    {
    mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut('s');
    mnu2.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_search_category_default);

    }
    MenuItem mnu3 = menu.add(0, 2, 2, "Delete");
    {
    mnu3.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    mnu3.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_delete);

    }
    MenuItem mnu4 = menu.add(0, 3, 3, "View");
    {
    mnu4.setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    mnu4.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details);
    }
    }
    private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
    {
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case 0:
    insert();
    return true;
    case 1:
     intent.setClass(ProduitActivity.this, Stock.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
    case 2:
     intent.setClass(ProduitActivity.this, Stock.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;

    case 3:
     intent.setClass(ProduitActivity.this, Stock.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;

    }
    return false;
    }

    public void createDB()
    {
    db=openOrCreateDatabase("produitbase.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
    db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    db.setLockingEnabled(true);
    db.setVersion(1);
    String sql="create table if not exists Produittable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nom_produit TEXT, quantite_stock TEXT, prix_vente TEXT, description_produit TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public void insert()
    {
     EditText nom_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nom_produit);
     EditText quantite_stock=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.quantite_stock);
     EditText prix_vente=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prix_vente);
     EditText description_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_produit);

     if(nom_produit.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer nom produit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (quantite_stock.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer la quantité.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (prix_vente.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer prix de vente.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (description_produit.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Entrer la description.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else 
    {

    String sql="insert into produittable(nom_produit,quantite_stock,prix_vente,description_produit) values('"+ nom_produit.getText().toString() +"','"+ quantite_stock.getText().toString() +"','"+ prix_vente.getText().toString() +"','"+ description_produit.getText().toString()+"')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
    clear();
    Toast.makeText(ProduitActivity.this, "Produit Ajouté.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    }
    public void clear()
    {
     EditText nom_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Nom_produit);
    EditText quantite_stock=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.quantite_stock);
    EditText prix_vente=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.prix_vente);
    EditText description_produit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.description_produit);

    nom_produit.setText("");
    quantite_stock.setText(""); 
    prix_vente.setText("");
    description_produit.setText("");

    nom_produit.clearFocus();
    quantite_stock.clearFocus();
    prix_vente.clearFocus();
    description_produit.clearFocus();

    nom_produit.requestFocus();
  }
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Check proper column name when you create table . it should be matched same when insert into.

Comment: if you edit your database you have to uninstall your application from device or emulator and then try to run

Comment: Post the part of code where you have created that table

Comment: i did it it show the same probléme why it says that no such column named description_produit and i declared it in String sql="create table if not exists Produittable(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nom_produit TEXT, quantite_stock TEXT, prix_vente TEXT, description_produit TEXT)";

Comment: Am I the only one who realise that your logcat says that column quantite_stock does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Your create SQL starts with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS. So my guess is you added the column **quantite_stock** while the device has already had that table. If this is the case then just reinstall the app - it will delete the DB, so you can be sure the table will be created with updated table columns.

Comment: thinks a lot its works i have reinstal it and i found a little problem in the table where insering i forgott '  <--- that

Comment: When I put togather the part hwo works with the other part of my application I get the same problem can you give me another possible solution Please i am stock in this column quantite_stock no sutch column why the logCat says that .

Comment: Hmm.. Is the Issue solved for which part the question asked??In your other part of application.. are you getting the same error, then first remove the sqlite table out through DDMS and check if correct table structure exist.. then recheck insert query such that column name as to be same...

Comment: Don't forget to upvote/mark answer correct if this post helped you to solve the problem